# UIColor with Hue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I have a tiny simple problem with the function

```
[UIColor colorWithHue: saturation: brightness: alpha: ]
```

I want to create a simple green color but with a bit less brightness like I already tested on "[This](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/color-scheme.htm)" site. This site told me I have to use the `RGB-color(163, 255, 133)` with a brightness of 76% or to say it in "HSL" it would has the value 105 (Saturation: 100%). So I thought okay easy doing lets code:

```
UIColor *green = [[UIColor alloc] initWithHue:105/360 saturation:1 brightness:0.76 alpha:1];
```

But when I test this line of code and debug it my green is a wine-red. The debug-session says that my `UIColor` `RGBA-code is (0.76, 0, 0, 1)`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSV, HSL, HSI and HSB are *not* interchangeable. To make matters worse, I believe that in some cases, there are different implementations of each representation that of course yield different results with converted to/from RGB, and, worse still, sometimes people think they are using HSL when in fact they are using HSV or some other such combo. So your best bet is to just keep trying until it works.

In your specific case, you need to find a way to convert from RGB to HSB (or HS*), and hope that your converter and the method of `UIColor` that you're calling do things the same way.

Also, `105/360` equals `0` in integer division, which is what you are using. Try using `double` values, e.g. `105.0/360.0` to get a `double` result.

Comment: Just as an aside, thanks to type promotion, only one argument needs to be double/float. The other will automatically promoted by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much dan! Very stupid mistake to forget the double values.. Now it works very well!

Comment: No problem. And as you have discovered and I forgot to note, one person's HSV is another person's HSL and so on.

Answer (score 0):

On provided homepage site, it appears that, when You change brightness, RGB also changes.. So You can probably skip the hue/saturation/brightness part and simply use RGB on application side like this:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:77/255.0f green:200/255.0f blue:57/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to use the brightness parameter so I need to use the "colorWithHue" function.